# Strange redirects to index page after submitting a POST form

Tags: php, forms, redirect, load

As the title suggests, I'm having strange behavior of my website which redirects me to the index.php page when I upload a 20mb+ file or just form data to phpmyadmin. For the form data, sometimes the form is submitted successfully but sometimes it just gets redirected to index page. I have not used any redirects to index page in my code which would redirect to the index page except for when the user hasn't logged in.

What I could think of is that it could be a timeout issue but its not because when I press the back button on the browser, I am still logged in and the form data is there.

I tried it on localhost and it works fine so the other thing I could think of is that the website is having issues. My website is running on Cpanel bronze package. Could it be because of the server load that the website cannot handle because of a low package?

Any help or suggestion would be helpful because I'm really stuck at this little hurdle...

This is a sample code where I am redirected to the index page but I really don't see a coding issue...

form_page.php:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
```

upload_file.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['check']<>1)
header("location:index.php?loginmsg=Please login first");
else
{
    $targetfolder = "resources/";
    $targetfolder = $targetfolder . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']) ;
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetfolder)) 
    {
        header("location:form_page.php?entrymsg2=File is uploaded!");
        exit();
    }
    else 
    {
        header("location:form_page.php?entrymsg2=Error uploading the file!");
        exit(); 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: We would like to help you, but in order to do so, we need to see some code to help you with.

Comment: use your browser network monitor to check what happened with your request, the first issue with uploading files maybe because you are limiting your max upload size in php.ini file

Comment: @Mitch i have uploaded the code for the file upload but i do think its not a coding problem but a server issue perhaps? Because if the file is too big, i should be getting the Error uploading the file! error but instead i get redirected to the index page

Comment: Could you show how `$_SESSION['check']` is being set please?

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius $_SESSION['check'] = 1; using this in the action page when a user logs in. It only redirects to the index page if the user has not logged in otherwise not. but i can assure you, the problem only occurs when submitting a form